# GNU Makefile, detect architecture

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I want to autodetect system architecture, when i compile my program under freebsd and i want 2 includes for x64 and x32  but don't work, i tried like this :

```
ifeq ($(uname -a),i386)
INCDIR += -I../../x32
else
INCDIR += -I../../x64
endif
```

What is wrong here?
When i compile on amd64 work with code below.
When i compile on i388 don't work.

When i compile on amd64 with code below the makefile see x64 dir.
When i compile on i386 with code below the makefile see x64 dir.
Soo bassicaly that else don't have any effect  ?

Comment: Try `uname -p` instead

Comment: Don't work.  this make me crazy... i can't understand why.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In GNU make syntax `$()` dereferences a variable. You rather want a shell command:

```
uname_p := $(shell uname -p) # store the output of the command in a variable
```

And then:

```
ifeq ($(uname_p),i386)
```

Alternative to multi-level `ifeq` using [computed variable names](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Computed-Names). Here is a working makefile I used on my system:

```
uname_s := $(shell uname -s)
$(info uname_s=$(uname_s))
uname_m := $(shell uname -m)
$(info uname_m=$(uname_m))

# system specific variables, add more here    
INCDIR.Linux.x86_64 := -I../../x64
INCDIR.Linux.i386 := -I../../x32

INCDIR += $(INCDIR.$(uname_s).$(uname_m))
$(info INCDIR=$(INCDIR))
```

Which produces the following output:

```
$ make 
uname_s=Linux
uname_m=x86_64
INCDIR=-I../../x64
```

Comment: ifeq ($(shell uname -p),i386)  Tried like this and don'tw work. :((((((((((((((((

Comment: @Starrrks_2 add `$(info $(shell uname -p))` and post its output.

Comment: I get  Illegal variable name. error  here is print  http://prntscr.com/asabll  and here is my system http://prntscr.com/asabv5

Comment: @Starrrks_2 Dude, these are commands in GNU Make syntax for a makefile. They are not supposed to work in a shell.

Comment: This is my makefile, check it please.   http://paste.ubuntu.com/15838571/    I'm not soo good in makefile so i don't know where to run syntax below

Comment: @Starrrks_2 I made a working makefile for you, try it on your system.

Comment: @Starrrks_2 I cannot review your code elsewhere, post your code here, so that people can see it, comment on it, and it does not disappear when you go away.