# How to find a base architecture inside Makefile?

Tags: linux, makefile, gnu-make, archlinux

I want to find inside a Makefile, whether I'm running on a 32-bit or 64-bit machine.

Is there any macro or environment variables that can be simply accessed from within Makefile?

I found this related answer on-line:

```
LBITS := $(shell getconf LONG_BIT)
ifeq ($(LBITS),64)
   # do 64 bit stuff here, like set some CFLAGS
else
   # do 32 bit stuff here
endif
```

However, I doubt in all system `getconf` tool would be available or not.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [GNU Makefile, detect architecture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36628165/gnu-makefile-detect-architecture)

Comment: @frist, no. I just rechecked - the answer is BSD-specific. I have added the more portable `uname -m` to my own answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**tl;dr;**

If all you need is to get the number of bits in `long` type in C in a portable way, it's ok to use `getconf LONG_BIT`.

Otherwise:

- to detect host architecture, use `config.guess` shell script
- to detect target architecture, use `gcc -dumpmachine` or `gcc --help=target`

---

### Detecting host architecture

#### 1) `getconf`

As mentioned by @Dummy00001, `getconf` is part of POSIX and is widely available, but it doesn't provide enough information.

Note that `getconf LONG_BIT` is just the number of bits in `long` type in C. E.g., it may be 32 on 16-bit or 64-bit machines. It's quite useless for determining host architecture.

#### 2) `uname`

`uname` is part of POSIX as well, and it doesn't provide enough information too.

For example, it doesn't distinguish between hardfloat and softfloat ARM on Linux. Also, its architecture naming is not really portable.

#### 3) `/proc`

You can use `/proc` to gather architecture info, e.g. `/proc/cpuinfo` on Linux. However, it's not portable and hard to parse.

#### 4) `config.guess`

Finally, I recommend GNU [`config.guess`](http://savannah.gnu.org/git/?group=config) script ([source code](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/config.git/plain/config.guess)). It is a standalone script that you can copy to your project. It is written in portable shell and should work on any UNIX.

```
$ sh config.guess
x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
```

This script is [used in autotools](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.69/html_node/Hosts-and-Cross_002dCompilation.html), but you can use it without autotools too.

---

### Detecting default target architecture of your toolchain

It usually makes sense to detect target architecture of toolchain being used. It's different from host architecture when cross-compiling.

#### 1) `gcc -E`

You can parse `gcc -E` output to get toolchain tuple for target architecture of gcc:

```
$ gcc -v -E - </dev/null |& grep Target:
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
```

This should work on any UNIX if you use GCC or clang.

Notes:

- It prints the value of `--target` option passed to `configure` script when GCC was built. It's not affected by current compilations flags passed to GCC, like `-m32` or `-march`.
- Unlike `config.guess`, this toolchain tuple is distro-specific. E.g., different schemes are used in prebuilt toolchains in [Debian](https://wiki.debian.org/Multiarch/Tuples) and [Gentoo](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Embedded_Handbook/Tuples).

#### 2) `gcc -dumpmachine`

It seems that `gcc -dumpmachine` [prints](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/9e87af5673c60242eeb42f9732ab64edd5810175/gcc/gcc.c#L3767) the [same](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/9e87af5673c60242eeb42f9732ab64edd5810175/gcc/gcc.c#L6613) value as previous recipe:

```
$ gcc -dumpmachine
x86_64-linux-gnu
```

It works with GCC and clang.

#### 3) `gcc -print-multiarch`

Another way to get toolchain tuple:

```
$ gcc -print-multiarch
x86_64-linux-gnu
```

It works with GCC, but not clang. Also, this option is known not to work in various cases:

- on Debian, it's empty if multilib is disabled
- on Gentoo, it's always empty
- as mentioned by @Dummy00001, it may be empty for cross-compilation toolchains (I guess it depends on how toolchain was built)

---

### Detecting target architecture depending on current flags

Some GCC options like `-m32` or `-march` can affect target architecture.

#### 1) `gcc --help=target`

This will print value of `-march` option deduced from default target architecture (configured when GCC was built) and current compilation options.

```
$ gcc -Q --help=target |& grep -e -march | awk '{print $2}'
x86-64

$ gcc -m32 -Q --help=target |& grep -e -march | awk '{print $2}'
i686

$ gcc -march=i386 -Q --help=target |& grep -e -march | awk '{print $2}'
i386
```

It doesn't work with clang.

Comment: Sadly `gcc -print-multiarch` doesn't work for ARM (works for Intel i386/x64 - but prints empty line in the ARM cross-compilation toolchain). Neither it is supported by `clang`. Similarly, your `gcc -v -E -`, shows the default GCC target, but doesn't react to -m32/-m64 flags. In other words, both your tool-chain suggestions are bad.

Comment: @Dummy00001, thanks. I've added your notes to the answer. BTW, `-print-multiarch` worked for ARM toolchains for me, so I guess it depends on how toolchain was built. I've also added `gcc --help=target` recipe that respects current CFLAGS like `-m32`.

Answer (score 2):

The [`getconf`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/getconf.html) is a POSIX tool, it should be available on all unix-like systems. But `uname -m` would be more portable and more traditional way to find the type of the system.

Otherwise, with high probability, you are looking in the wrong direction: the bit-ness of the host system doesn't necessarily match the bit-ness of the tool-chain. Tool-chain (compiler, linker) define what bit-ness the result would be. And the tool-chain could be customized by the user to accommodate for the local needs (e.g. compiling as 32-bit on a 64-bit OS), or even cross-compilation.

To find the bit-ness of the GCC (or clang) in your tool-chain, you can use that:

```
LBITS := $(shell $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -dM -E - </dev/null | grep -q "__LP64__" && echo 64 || echo 32)
```

Effectively, it queries what bit-ness the application is going to be compiled with, without doing actual compilation, but peeking at the compiler defines for the [LP parameter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/64-bit_computing#64-bit_data_models), which denotes the "data model" of the architecture (LP64 means "long and pointer are 64-bit" (and, by omission, int is 32 bit); ILP32 means "int, long and pointer are 32-bit").

As long as you stay on the Linux, that would work. (You need to use the `CFLAGS` in the compiler invocation, since `CFLAGS` overridden by the user could use the `-m32` or `-m64` options to change the bit-ness of the output code.)

Comment: I'm not looking for toolchain's bit-ness, just wanted to see my current system's bit-ness. However, you have given a great info. Thanks.

Comment: @Vicky, Rants: In recent times the amount of buggy software has risen: it mistakenly assumes that bit-ness of OS/HW is the bit-ness I need to compile for. E.g. in my case, I use lots of 32-bit software to be compatible as much as possible with the embedded 32-bit ARM. Yet, some libraries and applications, I can only compile in a VM, because their configure scripts all dumbly look at `uname -m`, and then later fail when GCC in 32-bit mode refuses to compile the 64-bit optimized parts.